Window accounts joned to the Active-Directory are locked, even if they hadn't put in wrong password
I'm working at my company and I have problem with window account.
Somer User call me and they said that Even if, He hadn't put in wrong password several times, The account were locked.
but they also said, they disconnect Lan, and then connect again, the account were unlocked.
There is no problem in AD's policy.
And User's computer has pointed adequete IP.
Also at ther server's eventviewer I confirmed Several 4740 Event but there are no error.
At the user's computer, I couldn't find event id 4625 that proof they put in wrong password.

What is the value of "Caller Computer Name" in the event 4740?
Please check all the audit failure logs in AD about this account, for example, 4771 or 4776, not only 4625.
